# Проблема со State в React Js

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть локальный файл, который подгружается на страницу. Я добавляю его в `state`, чтобы модифицировать его до тех пор пока пользователь не обновит сайт (после обновления данные возвращаются в исходное состояние).

У меня выпадает постоянно ошибка, когда я нажимаю на кнопку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Сами данные, которые в JSON отображаются, а после нажатия выпадает ошибка, что state не задан.

#### Код:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DishElement from "./DishElement";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import dataJson from "../../data/data.json";


class Category extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dishes: dataJson
        };
    }

    openToggle(id) {
        this.state ? 
            console.log("не null") :
            console.log("null")
    }


    render() {
        let dishes = this.state.dishes
        return (
                <section className={[styles.container, styles.container_column].join(" ")}>
                    {dishes.map((dish, index) => {
                        return <DishElement dish={dish} key={dish.name} openToggle={this.openToggle}/>
                    })}
                </section>
        )
    }
}

Category.propTypes = {
    dishes: PropTypes.array
}


export default Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден [был тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758081/loading-json-data-from-local-file-into-react-js)

надо заменить `openToggle={this.openToggle}` на `openToggle={(id) => this.openToggle(id)}`

Comment: можно было просто написать `this.openToggle.bind(this)`

Comment: @DmitriiSedovа интересное решение... А чем ваш вариант лучше моего? я просто новичок в ReactJS

Comment: По сути не чем особенно в данном случае, но согласно документации реакта  - `Проблема с этим синтаксисом заключается в том, что при каждом отображении кнопки ведения журнала создается другой обратный вызов. В большинстве случаев это нормально. Однако если этот обратный вызов передается в качестве опоры для более низких компонентов, эти компоненты могут выполнить дополнительную повторную визуализацию. Обычно мы рекомендуем привязку в конструкторе или использование синтаксиса полей класса, чтобы избежать такого рода проблем с производительностью.`

Comment: @DmitriiSedov напишете тогда как дополнительный ответ ниже моего?